# can't bind on address [47]: Address family not supported by protocol family

Tags: c, sockets

I'm working on a server software written in C. I created a function for setting up a global variable called `config`, so I can use this code in multiple projects.
The error message can you grab from the title.

```
typedef struct ntp_conn {
   int domain;     // addressfamily
   int sType;      // sockettype
   int protocol;   // protocol
   int socket;    // socketpointer
   struct sockaddr_in *addr; // address 
} ntp_conn;
```

and

```
int swf_config( int domain, int sType, int protocoll, char *ip, short int port ) {
    config->domain = domain;
    config->sType = sType;
    config->protocol = protocoll;

    config->addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    config->addr->sin_port = htons(port);
    config->addr->sin_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    if( inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &config->addr->sin_addr) < 0 )
        printf("\nerror...");

    return 0;
}
```

The server functions contains the socket creation, binding & listing finaly the main loop. The recived informations should be redirected to handler file which calculates a specific result. This parameter makes the function modular, right? ;)

swf_conn.c:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE  9084
#define MAXCONN 10

#include "swf_conn.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


ntp_conn *config;

void swf_error( char* msg ) {
    printf("\n** %s [%d]: %s", msg, errno, strerror(errno));
}

int swf_connect( ) {

    config->socket = socket( config->domain, config->sType, config->protocol);
    if( config->socket < 0 ) {
        swf_error("SOCKET-ERROR:");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if( connect((int)config->socket, (const struct sockaddr*)config->addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0 ) {
        swf_error("CONNECT-ERROR");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;
}

void swf_close( ) {
    close( config->socket );
    memset(&config, 0, sizeof(config));
}


int swf_config( int domain, int sType, int protocoll, char *ip, short int port ) {

    // Good idea?
    unsigned int addr;
    if( strcmp(ip, "INADDR_ANY") == 0 )
        addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    else
        addr = inet_addr(ip);

    config = (struct ntp_conn*) malloc(sizeof(struct ntp_conn));
    config->addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));


    config->domain = domain;
    config->sType = sType;
    config->protocol = protocoll;

    config->addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    config->addr->sin_port = htons(port);
    config->addr->sin_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    config->addr->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    memcpy( (char *)&config->addr->sin_addr, &addr, sizeof(addr));
    return 0;
}


int swf_put( const void *data ) {

    int recived = 0;
    int sended = 0;

    ntp_thread_recv *recvObj = malloc(sizeof(ntp_thread_recv));
    ntp_thread_recv *sendObj = malloc(sizeof(ntp_thread_recv));

    if( data == NULL ) {
        swf_error("send-error: parameter == NULL");
        exit(-1);
    }

    memcpy( &sendObj->data, &data, sizeof(data) );

    printf("\n** sending");
    sended = swf_send( sendObj );

    if( sended > 0 )
        printf("\n** sended %d bytes!\n**\n%s\n", (int)sended, (char*)sendObj->data);

    recived = swf_recv( recvObj );
    printf("\n** data recived! [%d]\n%s\n", (int)sizeof(recvObj), (char*) recvObj);

    return 0;
}

int swf_send( ntp_thread_recv *sendData ) {

    ssize_t sended = 0;
    int sendSize = sizeof(sendData->data);
    int i=0;

    do {
        sended = send( config->socket, &sendData->data[i], sendSize-sended, 0);
        if( sended < 0) {
            swf_error("send-error");
            exit(-1);
        }
    } while( sended < sendSize );

    return (int)sended;
}

int swf_recv( ntp_thread_recv *recvObj ) {

    ssize_t recived = 0;
    int recvLen = sizeof(char);
    char buffer = (char) malloc(recvLen);
    memset(&recvObj->data, 0, sizeof(recvLen*BUFFERSIZE));
    int i = 0;

    do {
        recived = recv( config->socket, &buffer, recvLen, 0);

        if( recived < 0) {
            swf_error("recv-error");
            exit(-1);
        }
        recvObj->data[(i++)] = buffer;
        printf("%s\n", recvObj->data);
        memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    } while ( recived > 0 && i < 20 );

    printf("%s", recvObj->data);
    return 0;

}

int swf_server( char *handleFile ) {
    int client[MAXCONN];
    struct sockaddr_in *clientAddr;
    unsigned int len;
    int i = 0;

    for( i=0; i<MAXCONN; i++)
        client[i] = 0;
    i=0;

    if( handleFile == NULL ) {
        swf_error("handleFile empty!");
        exit(-1);
    }

    config->socket = socket( config->domain, config->sType, config->protocol);
    if( config->socket < 0 ) {
        swf_error("SOCKET-ERROR:");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if( bind( config->socket, (const struct sockaddr*)&config->addr, sizeof(config->addr) ) < 0 ) {
        swf_error("can't bind on address");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if( listen( config->socket, MAXCONN ) < 0 ) {
        swf_error("can't listen on socket");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("\n** server waiting for connections...");

    for(;;) {

        if( ( client[i] = accept( config->socket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &len ) ) > 0 ) {

            ntp_thread_recv *sendObj = malloc(sizeof(ntp_thread_recv));
            ntp_thread_recv *recvObj = malloc(sizeof(ntp_thread_recv));

            sendObj->data = "welcome to my server!\n\r";

            if( swf_send(sendObj) < 0 ) {
                swf_error("sending error");
                continue;
            }

            memset(&sendObj, 0, sizeof(sendObj));

            FILE *fp;
            char *recvBuff[BUFFERSIZE];
            char buff;
            int j = 0;

            while( client[i] > 0 ) {


                if( swf_recv(recvObj) < 0 ) {
                    swf_error("reciving error");
                    continue;
                }

                if( strcmp( recvObj->data, "quit") == 0 ) {
                    client[i] = 0;
                    memset(&clientAddr, 0, sizeof(clientAddr));
                    printf("\n** client closed.");
                    continue;
                }

                strcat( recvBuff, handleFile );
                strcat( recvBuff, recvObj->data );


                if( ( fp = popen( recvBuff, "r" ) ) < 0 ) {
                    swf_error("can't execute the handle file!");
                    continue;
                }

                memset( &recvBuff, 0, sizeof(recvBuff) );
                while( ( buff = fgetc(fp) ) )
                    memcpy(&recvBuff[i++], &buff, sizeof(buff));

                if( j > 0 ) {
                    memcpy(&sendObj->data, &recvBuff, (j+1)*sizeof(char));
                } else {
                    sendObj->data = "nothingtosend\n\r";
                    swf_error("can't read result from your handle file!");
                }
                j = 0;

                memset(&recvBuff, 0, sizeof(recvBuff));

                if( swf_send(sendObj) < 0 ) {
                    swf_error("sending error");
                    continue;
                }

                memset(&sendObj, 0, sizeof(sendObj));

            }

        } else {
            client[i] = 0;
        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "swf_conn.h"
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *ip = "0.0.0.0";
    //   char *buff = ( char * ) malloc( 1024 * sizeof( char ) );

    printf("\n      SERVER\n");

    printf("\n%s", ip);

    if( swf_config( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, ip, 81) < 0 )
        printf("\n** ERROR: ");
    else
        printf("\n** socket created...");

    if( swf_server("./handleFile") < 0 )
        printf("\n** error!");


    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
      SERVER

0.0.0.0
** socket created...
** can't bind on address [47]: Address family not supported by protocol family
```

on this point should be my fault, but I don't get it.
Thanks for help!

sorry for missing code!

Comment: Please cook your problem code down to a minimal example. Here there is a lot of stuff that is not useful for your problem, and there are missing parts. So we really can't understand where your problem lies.

Comment: I'd check sw_config(), by adding errno check. According to [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html), inet_pton() "0 is returned if src does not contain a character string representing a valid network address in the specified address family. If af does not contain a valid address family, -1 is returned and errno is set to EAFNOSUPPORT."

Answer (score 0):

You appear never to be allocating any memory for `config->addr`. I suspect that's at least one problem.

Would it not be easier to have:

```
typedef struct ntp_conn {
   int domain;              // addressfamily
   int sType;               // sockettype
   int protocol;            // protocol
   int socket;              // socketpointer
   struct sockaddr_in addr; // address <- NOTE NO '*' HERE 
} ntp_conn;
```

so you don't have to worry about that?

Comment: I do. I didn't post this code, because I thought the problem is on another line. I tried to prevent useless spam ;). Anyway xCode doesn't like, when I try to build my code with your struct. And the simple http request with my send and recive functions works as well with this `swf_config`.

Comment: I suggest you reduce your problem to a simple manageable program where you are showing all the code. Often you find this process will make your program suddenly work, and you then need to work out what you fixed by simplifying it. If not, then post the program here.

Comment: Note that `sockaddr_in` is specific to `AF_INET` only, but many socket functions take a `sockaddr*` pointer where the `sin_family` member denotes what type of `sockaddr_...` struct is actually being used `(for instance, `AF_INET6` uses `sockaddr_in6`). So it makes more sense for `ntp_conn` to use `SOCKADDR_STORAGE` instead of `sockaddr_in` directly.